# Single result from database using mysqli

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

I am trying to use mySQLi for the first time. I have done it in the case of loop. Loop results are showing but I am stuck when I try to show a single record. Here is loop code that is working.

```
<?php
// Connect To DB
$hostname="localhost";
$database="mydbname";
$username="root";
$password="";

$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
?>

<?php
$query = "SELECT ssfullname, ssemail FROM userss ORDER BY ssid";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>

<?php
/*Loop through each row and display records */
for($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>

Name: <?php print $row['ssfullname']; ?>
<br />
Email: <?php print $row['ssemail']; ?>
<br /><br />

<?php 
// end loop
} 
?>
```

How do I show a single record, any record, name, or email, from the first row or whatever, just a single record, how would I do that?
In a single record case, consider all the above loop part removed and let's show any single record without a loop.

Comment: ...ORDER BY ssid LIMIT 1  also remove for($i = ..){}

Comment: Actually i want to remove the loop part and and without limit i want to get one record with query to show single record.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

When just a single result is needed, then no loop should be used. Just fetch the row right away.

- In case you need to fetch the entire row into associative array:

  ```
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  ```
- in case you need just a single value:

  ```
    //starting from PHP 8.1
    $value = $result->fetch_column();
    // for older versions:
    $value = $result->fetch_row()[0] ?? false;
  ```

Below are complete examples for different use cases

### Variables to be used in the query

When variables are to be used in the query, then a **prepared statement** must be used. For example, given we have a variable `$id`:

PHP >= 8.2

```
// get a single row
$sql = "SELECT fullname, email FROM users WHERE id=?";
$row = $conn->execute_query($query, [$id])->fetch_assoc();

// just a single value
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE id=?";
$count = $conn->execute_query($query, [$id])->fetch_column();
```

Legacy PHP versions:

```
// get a single row
$query = "SELECT fullname, email FROM users WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

// just a single value
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM userss WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$count = $result->fetch_row()[0] ?? false;
```

The detailed explanation of the above process can be found in my [article](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select). As to why you must follow it is explained in this famous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

### No variables in the query

When no variables to be used in the query, you can use the `query()` method:

```
// array
$user = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1")->fetch_assoc();
// value
$count = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM users")->fetch_column();
// value < 8.1
$count = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM users")->fetch_row()[0];
```

Comment: Yes that's object oriented programming. It scares me bcoz it seems difficult. But I want to learn it badly. Please recommend a place/source where I can learn about classes and use of class and objects etc.

Comment: You need to know OOP only to *write* classes. While using them do not require no special knowledge, it is as easy as calling a regular function. The only difference is a little prefix `$class->` before function name. The rest is the same.

Answer (score 12):

Use  `mysqli_fetch_row()`. Try this,

```
$query = "SELECT ssfullname, ssemail FROM userss WHERE user_id = ".$user_id;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row   = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

$ssfullname = $row['ssfullname'];
$ssemail    = $row['ssemail'];
```

Comment: You can't do that with mysqli_fetch_row as it returns an enumerated array.   
Ex: `$row[0], $row[1]`  
You need to use mysqli_fetch_assoc, which returns an associative array, if you want to specify field names.  
Ex: `$row['ssfullname'];`

Answer (score 7):

If you assume just one result you could do this as in Edwin suggested by using specific users id.

```
$someUserId = 'abc123';

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ssfullname, ssemail FROM userss WHERE user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $someUserId);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($ssfullname, $ssemail);
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();

ChromePhp::log($ssfullname, $ssemail); //log result in chrome if ChromePhp is used.
```

OR as "Your Common Sense" which selects just one user.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ssfullname, ssemail FROM userss ORDER BY ssid LIMIT 1");

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($ssfullname, $ssemail);
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();
```

Nothing really different from the above except for ***PHP v.5***

Answer (score 2):

The first answer will do the job but in this case you don't need to loop the result.

```
$row = $result->fetch_row();
```

Just echo the column

```
  echo   $row['column'];
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

### As of PHP 8.1, `mysqli_result::fetch_column()` is available

You can use `mysqli_result::fetch_column()` to fetch a single scalar value from the result set.

The new method accepts 0-based position of the column you want to read. The default value is 0.

```
$query = "SELECT ssfullname, ssemail FROM userss WHERE ud=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$id])
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$ssemail = $result->fetch_column(1);
```

Beware that this method will move the internal pointer to the next row, just like the other `fetch_*` methods do. When it reaches the end, it will return `false`. Therefore, in the above example, you would be better off using `fetch_assoc()` to fetch the entire row into an array.

It can also be used with `mysqli::query()` for SQL statements without parameters.

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM userss";
$count = $conn->query($query)->fetch_column();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **`$row = $query->fetch();`** try to use:

```
$result = $query->get_result();
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
```

every time you can check if you get data from mysql tables by displaying them using:

`var_export( $row['put your column name here'] );`