# How to destructure mysqli_result row

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

How does one destructure a row from a mysqli_result?
This pattern works with PDO, but I'd like to be able to use the same with mysqli.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('', 'pdo', '123', 'pdo');
foreach ($mysqli->query("select uid, name from users") as [$uid, $name])
  print("$uid: $name\n");

// PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 on line 3
// PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1 on line 3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single Result from Database by using mySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624509/single-result-from-database-by-using-mysqli)

Comment: What is *legacy code* actually?

Comment: `$mysqli->query()` returns a bool.

Comment: Then the query run into an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only iterate `mysqli_result` using associative arrays.

```
foreach ($mysqli->query("select uid, name from users") as ['uid' => $uid, 'name' => $name]) {
    print "$uid: $name\n";
}
```

However, I would advise using `fetch_all()` which will fetch everything into an array, even using numerical keys.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("select uid, name from users")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);
foreach ($result as [$uid, $name]) {
    print "$uid: $name\n";
}
```

Comment: `fetch_all()` is sub optimal, especially for larger results, but it seems to be the only supported way.